# Increasing AsyncStorage size limit in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to increase the size limit of 6mb in my native application. I have already tried this process:

```js
import com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier;

@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    long size = 50L * 1024L * 1024L; // 50 MB
    com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setMaximumSize(size);
  }
```

But this doesn't show any effect on my application as i have put this code on mainApplication.java. Is there any other way to increase the default size? Thanks in advance.